# How to handle branching within Promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am implementing a passwordless auth flow with AWS Cognito. It UI related logic so I tend to choose not blocking the thread by using `Promise` only (no `async` & `await`). Doing something like below still make me feel, I am writing another "Promise version" of callback hell.

```
  const session = await getSession();

  if (!session) {
    try {
      const user = await signUp(emailAddress);
    } catch (error) {
      try {
        const state = await resendConfirmationCode();
      } catch {
        await forgotPassword();
      }
    }
  }
```

I **do** know that I could chain all the function together using `then` but the response in the subsequent `then` is actually depends on the result got in the last `then` that is the reason why I am asking how to handle branching inside a Promise (OR `then`).

All methods return `thenable`. I had a hard time to figure out a way to implement this using pure `Promise` and `then`. It was pretty straightforward using `callback`s.

[image]

```
export const doInitAuth = emailAddress => {
  getSession()
    .then(
      // Step 01 Check there is a current live session (Optional)
      session => {
        return null; // stopped the auth flow and dropped `session`
      },
      error => {
        // Step 02 Signup a new account
        return signUp(emailAddress).then(
          userData => {
            return null; // stopped the auth flow and dropped `userData`
          },
          error => {
            // Resend account verification code if user already signed up
            return resendConfirmationCode().then(
              result => {
                return null; // stopeed the auth flow and dropped `result`
              },
              error => {
                return forgotPassword(); // HACK: (Xinyang) There is a limit for number of time a user can "forgot" the password in a given time
              }
            );
          }
        );
      }
    )
    .catch(error => {
      throw Error("Unhandled error in the auth flow", error);
    });
};
```

Ideally, I want to have this done without additional lib.

Comment: The shortest answer is: use functions. You don't need to have everything in a massive block. Once you add functions and reduce indentation the answer might become obvious.

Comment: Let's say this was entirely synchronous - how would it look like?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum give me a sec let me code a sync version.

Comment: @XinyangLi I left an answer, not sure it's what you meant or what you want but let me know if it works out for you - it can also be made even shorter - but that would hurt readability in my opinion so I opted for relative verboseness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using promises and modern Node - there is absolutely no reason to not use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) which lets you write asynchronous code synchronously.

In addition, let's write a little helper that inspects the promise flow since you're using exceptions for flow control which is a big no-no in general:

```
const reflect = p => p.then(value => ({ state: 'fulfilled', value }), 
                            error => ({ state: 'rejected', error }));
```

Now, let's rewrite it without using exceptions for non-exceptional flow control:

```
export const doInitAuth = async emailAddress => {
  if ((await reflect(getSession()).state === 'fulfilled') return; // already has a live session
  if ((await reflect(signUp(emailAddress))).state === 'fulfilled') return; // signed up successfully
  if ((await reflect(resendConfirmationCode())).state === 'fulfilled') return; // sent confirmation email
  if ((await reflect(forgotPassword())).state === 'fulfilled') return;
  // deal with what you want to do in case forgotPassword failed here  
};
```

The reason your code looks "weird" is because you are using exceptions for flow control - not having a session, not being able to sign up with a taken email etc are all reasonable and not exceptional scenarios and you should consider not using exceptions for them.

Comment: but my concern is using `async` and `await` would **block** UI from update right? I'm wiring a browser side solution not in NodeJS.

Comment: @XinyangLi the whole point of async/await is that it's _as easy as blocking_ but it does not block. That's the beauty of it. As someone who wrote several promise libraries and helps maintain some of the biggest ones (bluebird, Q) and works on promises for Node.js - I never write promises without async/await anymore :)

Comment: That's why async/await is so awesome, it's just promises under the hood. It keeps a state machine in the background that uses the same machinery as promise chaining (and generators) and keeps the state and re-enters the function when the promise resolves. It is still event based and asynchronous.

Comment: okay, thanks @benjamin I think I need to understand `async` more, reading http://exploringjs.com/es2016-es2017/ch_async-functions.html

Comment: @XinyangLi sure, that's a very good book (I was a reviewer) - if you have any questions about it please don't hesitate to ask here or email me or axel. Glad I could help!